How to Avoid Adding Padding Top Before the First Row in TCPDF Table?
I'm using TCPDF to generate a PDF document, and I'm encountering an issue where there's an unwanted padding or space at the top of the table before the first row. Here's the relevant code and a screenshot of the issue:
$html = '
<h5 style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">Outcome Details</h5>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100px; padding: 0;">
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">Passport Number:</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">Passport Country:</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">Visa Class:</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">Visa Granted:</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">Visa Expires:</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">Entitlements:</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 440px; padding: 0;">
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">' . $document_number . '</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">' . $document_country . '</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">VC/' . $visa_subclass . '</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">2022-06-09+10:00</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">2024-08-30+10:00</p>
        <p style="font-size: 9px; margin: 0;">' . $entitlements . '</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
';

// Output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html);


As you can see, there's a white space at the top of the table before the first row. I've already tried setting the padding and margin to zero, but the issue persists.
How can I remove this unwanted space? Any help would be appreciated!

try this   Outcome Details

No, padding and margin does not work with TCPDF. If I use  then it does not add padding-top but adds leading white space which is also I don't want.

i found a solution its not to use 'p' or any other tags simply do this instead:
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 110px; font-size: 9px;">Passport Number:</td>
        <td style="width: 440px; font-size: 9px;">'.$document_number.'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 110px; font-size: 9px;">Passport Country:</td>
        <td style="width: 440px; font-size: 9px;">'.$document_country.'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 110px; font-size: 9px;">Visa Class:</td>
        <td style="width: 440px; font-size: 9px;">VC/'.$visa_subclass.'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 110px; font-size: 9px;">Visa Granted:</td>
        <td style="width: 440px; font-size: 9px;">2022-06-09+10:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 110px; font-size: 9px;">Visa Expires:</td>
        <td style="width: 440px; font-size: 9px;">2024-08-30+10:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 110px; font-size: 9px;">Entitlements:</td>
        <td style="width: 440px; font-size: 9px;">'.$entitlements.'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 110px; font-size: 9px;">Entitlements Conditions:</td>
        <td style="width: 440px; font-size: 9px;">'.generateEntitlementConditionNumbers().'</td>
      </tr>
</table>

